# While writing npm install learnyounode -g on terminal? 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, nodejs, npm

```
~$ npm install learnyounode -g

npm ERR! registry error parsing json

npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type"content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/><title></title><script type="text/javascript">StaticRequestInfo={Referer:document.referrer};function EscapeBrowserFrame(){try{if(window.top.location==window.self.location){}else{window.top.location.href=document.location.href}}catch(Error){}}function SetRequestTitle(){document.title=document.domain}function InitiateFrameRequest(){var url = "/?acc=0F4B1727-114A-4EF2-AC1B-1DB964D84818&ref=install+learnyounode&framerequest=1&pcc=";document.write("<frameset rows=\"100%,*\" frameborder=\"no\" border=\"0\" framespacing=\"0\"><frame src=\""+url+"\" name=\"landingparent\" id=\"landingparent\">
<\/frameset>")}SetRequestTitle();EscapeBrowserFrame();</script></head><script type="text/javascript">InitiateFrameRequest();</script><body><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?acc=0F4B1727-114A-4EF2-AC1B-1DB964D84818&ref=install+learnyounode&framerequest=1&noscript=1&pcc="></noscript><noframes><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/?acc=0F4B1727-114A-4EF2-AC1B-1DB964D84818&ref=install+learnyounode&framerequest=1&noscript=1&pcc="></noframes></body></html>
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:274:23)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:251:7
npm ERR!     at Gunzip.onEnd (zlib.js:167:5)

npm ERR!     at Gunzip.emit (events.js:117:20)

npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:944:16

npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,

npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:

npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>


npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-44-generic

npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "learnyounode" "-g"

npm ERR! cwd /home/hypertext

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37

npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28

npm ERR! type unexpected_token

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hypertext/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

================================================================
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm config set proxy http:
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm config get proxy
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http:"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
null
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm config get https-proxy
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http:"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
null
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$

Comment: hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ node -v
v0.10.37
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm -v
1.4.28
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm install express
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: My PC have dual boot functionality, one is windows and other Ubuntu?
Does it interfere for this npm installation?

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: nodejs-dev
       Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
      
       Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
    
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Add the output into your question and not in the comments

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to SSL certificates, and it's most common when you're [trying to run `npm` from behind a proxy](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9036).  There are a few ways to remedy this issue:

- You can [reset npm's proxy settings](http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.ch/2013/11/set-and-reset-proxy-for-git-and-npm.html) by running:

  - `npm config rm proxy`
  - `npm config rm https-proxy`
- You can use the non-https version of npm:

  - `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm config set proxy http:
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm config get proxy
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http:"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
null
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ npm config get https-proxy
npm WARN invalid config proxy="http:"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
null
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$

Comment: It's telling you that `http:` isn't a valid proxy URL, you need a full URL like `http://someurl:8080` (where `8080` is the port of your proxy). If you aren't behind a proxy or don't care about using the https version of npm, `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` will definitely be the easiest solution.